# What is the Time and space complexity of sort() in C++ with custom comparator function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

Consider the following code-

```
 bool cmp(pair<string,int> &a, pair<string,int> &b) {
     return ((a.second > b.second) || (a.second==b.second && a.first<b.first));
 }

vector<pair<string,int>> v;

sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
```

For this case, what would be my complexity? Will it be `O(nlogn)` ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: What is the complexity of your comparator ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::sort` has time complexity: ***O(NlogN) custom comparisons***.
But in your case the comparator function `cmp` also performs **string comparison**,

> (a.second==b.second && a.first<b.first)

`std::basic_string operator<`  has time complexity linear in the size of the strings.


Hence, worst case complexity is ***O(K*NlogN) char comparisons***, where K is length of the string.

Comment: It helps to be clear about O(x) _of what_.  `std::sort` is always O(NlogN) _custom comparisons_, but if the comparison itself does linear char comparisons, then the total is O(KNlogN) _char comparisons_.

Comment: @MooingDuck I see, thanks for pointing out.